# Using contour integration to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos (m \phi)}{5+3 \cos(\phi)}\,d\phi$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I recently started learning about contour integrals and I have the following problem:

> Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(m\phi)}{5+3\cos(\phi)} d\phi$

My work so far has been the following:

Let the contour $\gamma$ be {$z=e^{i\phi}:0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$} and make the substitution $z=e^{i\phi}$ to obtain

$\displaystyle{\oint_\gamma \frac{(z^m+z^{-m})\frac{1}{2}}{5+\frac{3}{2}(z+z^{-1})}\frac{dz}{iz}}$

After some algebra the integral I believe becomes

$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{3i} \oint_\gamma \frac{z^{2m}+1}{z^m(z+3)(z+\frac{1}{3})}}dz$

From this point, I would like to apply the Residue theorem to obtain

$2\pi i [\operatorname{Res}(f;0)+\operatorname{Res}(f;\frac{1}{3})]$, where $f=\displaystyle{\frac{z^{2m}+1}{z^m(z+3)(z+\frac{1}{3})}}$. However at this point I get a bit lost, as I'm unsure how to compute the residue at $0$? Any advice or hints on how to proceed would be appreciated!

Comment: $\dfrac{z^{2m}+1}{z^m}=z^m+\dfrac1{z^m}$ so you can ignore the first term in the numerator of $f$.

Comment: There is a calculational mistake in the step from the second integral to the third. The denominator  in the integrand of the third integral should be $z^m (z+3) (z+1/3)$.

Comment: @Hyperson you’re right, I missed that thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

I propose the following method, which has the benefit of never introducing a [non-removable] singularity at zero.  First, note that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(m\phi)}{5+3\cos(\phi)}\, d\phi$$
is the real part of
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i|m|\phi}}{5+3\cos(\phi)}\, d\phi.$$
We evaluate this integral instead.

---

Using the method used in the question, but on this integral, we find that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i|m|\phi}}{5+3\cos(\phi)}\, d\phi = \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^{|m|}}{5+\frac32(z+z^{-1})}\,\frac{dz}{iz} = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{-2iz^{|m|}/(3z+9)}{z+1/3}\,dz$$

This integrand has a simple pole at $z=-1/3$ and no other singularities inside $|z|=1$.  As a result, the integral has the value
$$2\pi i \cdot \frac{-2i(-1/3)^{|m|}}{3(-1/3)+9} = \frac{\pi}{2}\left(-\frac13\right)^{|m|}$$
which is already real, so it's the answer to the original problem too.

Comment: Note that we could have guessed that the imaginary part was zero at the beginning, because the imaginary part of the integrand was $\sin(|m|\phi) / (5 + 3\cos(\phi))$, which is $2\pi$-periodic and odd [and continuous, so integrable].  As a result, the integral over any inteval of length $2\pi$ of the imaginary part of the integrand would be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to proceed.  Here, we note that we can write for $|z|<1/3$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z^m(z+3)(z+1/3)}&=\frac1{z^{m}(1+z/3)(1+3z)}\\\\
&=\frac1{z^{m}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(-3)^n}z^n\sum_{p=0}^\infty (-3)^p z^p \\\\
&=\frac{1}{z^{m}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^\infty (-3)^{p-n}z^{p+n}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{z^{m}}\sum_{q=0}^\infty\sum_{p=0}^q (-1)^q(3)^{2p-q}z^q\\\\
\end{align}$$

The residue is at zero is the coefficient on the term $1/z$, which occurs when $q=m-1$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^{2m+1}+1}{z^m(z+3)(z+1/3)}, z=0\right)&=\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^m(z+3)(z+1/3)}, z=0\right)\\\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{p=0}^{m-1} (3)^{2p-m-1}\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{8}\left(3^{m+1}-\frac1{3^{m-1}}\right)
\end{align}$$

The residue at $z=-1/3$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^{2m+1}+1}{z^m(z+3)(z+1/3)}, z=-1/3\right)
&=-\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{8}3^{m+1}+\frac{(-1)^m}{8}\frac1{3^{m-1}}
\end{align}$$

Adding the residues, multiplying by $2\pi i$ and multiplying by $\frac1{3i}$, we find the value of the integral of interest is therefore,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(m\phi)}{5+3\cos(\phi)}\,d\phi=\frac{(-1)^{m}\pi}{2(3)^m}$$